# How to convert vob to wmv with ffmpeg with medium quality?

Tags: .net, video, ffmpeg, wmv, vob

if use as parameters:

```
string.Format("-i {0} -vcodec wmv2 -acodec wmav2 -sameq {1}", inputFileName, outPutFileName)
```

output file size is very big.
if use :

```
string.Format("-i {0} -vcodec wmv2 -acodec wmav2 {1}", inputFileName, outPutFileName)
```

output file quality is ery low.
How to get medium quality with ffmpeg?

Comment: [`-sameq` does not mean "same quality"](http://superuser.com/a/478550/110524): do not use it. Please show your actual ffmpeg commands and the complete console outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Quality of encoding controls by "-qmax X" parameter, where "X" is number between 1 and 10. 1 means the same quality, 10 is bad quality.